# How to use a google-code project in Android-Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-code

I'm trying to use a project from google-code in Android Studio.
https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/
I'm not all that familiar with AS, gradle, etc, yet. 
Is there a way to import the project to AS or build it from scratch (Without using eclipse!). I already did a checkout and have the project on my local drive. 
The project has the structure:
gen\
res\
src\
.classpath
.project
default.properties
AndroidManifest.xml

All I'm getting, when I try to import it into AS, is: [image]